# How to retrieve addresses within the zip code by zip code, I searched for the API, but it did not solve my problem

Tags: here-api

I now need to pass a zip code to get a detailed address list (the picture below has the desired effect), I try to use it https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?qq=postalCode=D04+WR52, but it returns only the information of this zip code area, not the address list. I am very confused now. I use this API in the UK

[image: example]

Comment: Is there any 3rd party API for same? I am also looking for addresses using post code.

Comment: The one I use is free. But it only provides UK postcode query, you can try searching other APIs. Because this is a third-party API platform.    
     [https://english.api.rakuten.net/samsinfield/api/postcodes-4-u-uk-address-finder]

Answer (score 0):

The postal code is premium content to access, depending on your plan. Contact your vendor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, here map basic service charges and free functions are the same

Comment: If you have other third-party services that can obtain the relevant address through the zip code, please let me know, I am very grateful.

Comment: My recommendation is Here due to the quality of the data. But to get access to the detailed postal code data, you need to choose a differentiated paid plan that allows you to access the detailed address from the postal code data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, it looks like you need to use [discover](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-discover-brief.html) or [autosuggest](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html) (**not** [geocode](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-geocode-brief.html))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have used the two documents you provided, but still can’t solve my problem. Use
 'autosuggest' is a good suggestion, but the project function needs to use the zip code. If you have other third-party services that can obtain the relevant address through the zip code, please let me know, thank you very much.

Comment: You can use Google Maps API - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Google provides the automatic search does not seem to list the address, you provide the URL, search ls29hb, you can see, very sorry. It's too difficult. I don't know how the developer of my screenshot implements it.

Comment: I don't think I can make it. Thank you. I'll try to contact the developer and share this skill with you when I succeed.